# Decompress tar file into directory

Tags: php, exec, tar, compression

I'm trying to decompress a tar file into a directory, but have no idea how.
I can extract it to the same directory as the tar file, but not into another folder.

```
$filename = "homedir.tar";
exec("tar xvf $filename");
```

Have tried the following, but it does not work (nothing is being extracted):

```
exec("tar -C, homedir zxvf $filename");
```

Update:

This is the content of my file:

```
# Absolute paths
$filepath = "/home/acc/public_html/test/test/homedir.tar";
$folderpath = "/home/acc/public_html/test/test/homedir";

# Check if folder exist
if(!is_dir($folderpath)) {
    die('Folder does not exist');
}

# Check if folder is writable
if(!is_writable($folderpath)) {
    die('Folder is not writable');
}

# Check if file exist
if(!file_exists($filepath)) {
    die('File does not exist');
}

exec("tar -C $folderpath -zxvf $filepath");
```

No errors, but nothing is being decompresses either.

Comment: Is pear tar installed on your webserver?

Comment: try passing an empty array as the second param and then inspecting the contents of that array. It will show you all the output which may give you a clue about what's going wrong. see: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I tried that, return empty $status = array();
exec("tar -C $folderpath -zxvf $filepath", $status);
print_r($status);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma from the -C and add the dash before zxvf:

```
exec("tar -C $outdir -zxvf $infile");
```

Or you can put the -C part on the end and you don't need the dash before zxvf:

```
exec("tar zxvf $infile -C $outdir");
```

And you should probably make sure that your paths are absolute, just to be sure.

Comment: Getting this in my error_log: [06-Sep-2011 14:39:11] PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0